# Gunicorn StatsD Metrics

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am hosting a flask app using Gunicorn. I have enabled telemetry using Gunicorn statsD. The Gunicorn metrics are being emitted fine to influxdb. However, I am not able to figure out a way to emit a few custom application metrics.

I looked through the code and it seems that Gunicorn just overwrites the standard logger for emitting metrics. So, if I get access to the logger I assume metrics can be emitted. However, I am not able to get access to the logger.

Any pointers on how to make this work ?